# Get transformation from small bounding box to larger bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, transform, coordinate-transformation

I have coordinates of the four corners of a large bounding box within an image and I also have the coordinates of a smaller bounding box within the larger one. Is there any way in python code that I can get the transformation info from small to big box coordinates so that I can apply this transformation to any box coordinates and receive its corresponding larger box coordinates? Perhaps using openCV?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple ratios,
if you define define your boxes with bottom-left and top-right coordinates.

```py
smallBox = ((x0, y0), (x1, y1))
bigBox = ((x2, y2), (x3, y3))
width = lambda box: box[1][0] - box[0][0]
length = lambda box: box[1][1] - box[0][1]
ratio = (width(bigBox)/width(smallBox), length(bigBox)/length(smallBox))
transform_axis = lambda axis, units: bigBox[0][axis]+(units - smallBox[0][axis])*ratio[axis]
transform = lambda x, y: (transform_axis(0, x), transform_axis(1, y))
```